# Wordpress - ACF: list titles of all articles associated with a certain post type and custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress in combination with advanced custom fields plugin.

I am trying to achieve something – which I guess is probably pretty simply or have been covered already. Unfortunately I do not really know for what to search, so it would be great to receive some help from you guys.

I have a custom post type with the name „test“. This custom post type has a custom field with a multiple select field „multiple“ – this field contains two possible values „value1“ and „value2“.

Now I have a common page where I want to alphabetically(!) list the title of all(!) articles of the custom post type „test“ which have the value „value1“ selected.

My question: how to achieve this?! :)

Really looking forward to your help and answers!

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'test', 'posts_per_page' => 99 ) );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

if( get_field('multiple')=='value1') {
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
}

endwhile;
```

Comment: What code have you tried? If you haven't already attempted to solve this take a look at the docs for `WP_Query`. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Great, thanks. How's the code above working for you? Are you getting any output from it?

Comment: It is working without "if( get_field('multiple')=='value1') {"

But as written I am trying to recieve the posts which have a certain value for the custom field "multiple". This is the problem I am having.

Comment: Can you add `echo '<pre>'; print_r( get_post_custom() ); echo '</pre>';` inside the loop and let me know the output.

Comment: Sure. Here we go:

    Array
(
    [_edit_last] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [_edit_lock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1426785628:1
        )

    [multiple] => Array
        (
            [0] => a:1:{i:0;s:11:“value1“;}
        )

    [_multiple] => Array
        (
            [0] => field_550b04a4e4b0f
        )

)

------

I tried to play around with this, but couldn't find a working solution...

Comment: The issue you have is your multiple field is being saved as a serialized array. You need to change the field type or it won't work.

Comment: Really? :( I played around with different field types within advanced custom fields plugin. Unfortunately all "multi select" fields, like checkbox or multiselect, always are saved as a serialized array?!

No option to write a if function with these field types?

Comment: solved :)
by plaing around with different field types. Thank you Nathan!!